# Access Flags for Handles

Tags: access-control

The handles window in process Explorer has a column Access which supposedly determines the access rights of that particular handle. I am not able to get any documentation on how to read the flags and what each bit means. Any resource to point me in the direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Window Handle can be accessed by anything which has access to Process Handle. About the flags I never investigated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find those defined in winnt.h.  (A sample [winnt.h](http://source.winehq.org/source/include/winnt.h) which seems to match correctly can be found included in the Wine project.)  The lower 16 bits are context-dependent (eg. they are interpreted differently depending on whether the handle is for a file, a threat, a process, etc.)

The bit patterns can be further described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).